# Need help understanding the derivation of Hydrostatic Equilibrium in a star

Tags: proof-explanation, physics

First and foremost I am sorry for this; in order to make my questions clear I must first upload the lecture notes from my institution $^\zeta$ for the derivation of Hydrostatic Equilibrium:

[image: Hydrostatic Equilibrium 1]

[image: Hydrostatic Equilibrium 2]

---

$^\zeta$ Lecture notes courtesy of Imperial College London, Astrophysics dept, 2017-2018 edition.

---

Firstly, in equation $(3.1)$ why is there no negative sign for $F_g$? Last time I checked, Newton's law of gravitation told us that

$$F=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

Nextly, I have a conceptual problem with equation $(3.2)$; when they use the term 'pressure' I am going to assume that they are referring to the **radiation pressure** that is released due to nuclear fusion reactions taking place in the sun. In that formula it must be the case that $P(r) \gt P(r+\delta r)$ if this is the case then $(3.2)$ should read $$F_p=-\left(\frac{dP}{dr}\right)\delta r\,\delta A $$

Correct me if I'm wrong but Hydrogen nuclei are fused together to generate the more stable Helium and hence lots of radiation pressure acting outwards from the centre of the star. If this is correct then $P(r+\delta r)=0$, since the outside face of that cylindrical volume element in **Figure $3.1$** will not 'feel' any of this radiation pressure because this pressure only acts on the inner face. What am I not understanding here?

Moving on to equation $(3.3)$, let's suppose the sign of the gravitational force in $(3.1)$ really is neglected. Does this mean that the negative sign in $(3.3)$ is due to $P(r+\delta r) \lt P(r)$ and hence $$\frac{GM(r)\rho(r)}{r^2}=-\left(\frac{dP}{dr}\right)\,?$$ I know this is the same equation as in $(3.3)$ but I have written it with the negative sign next to the pressure differential as I would like to know where this minus sign originates from. Does anyone know?

My final concern is the sign in $(3.4)$ as last time I checked $$g=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$$ and **not** $$g=\frac{GM}{r^2}$$

Hence, equation $(3.4)$ should read 
$$\left(\frac{dP}{dr}\right)=\rho(r)\,g\,?$$

---

I forgot to mention that I have done some research and [this](http://burro.astr.cwru.edu/Academics/Astr221/StarPhys/hydrostat.html) is the closest derivation I could find, which, needless to say is no less helpful than the notes I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pressure they are talking about is not radiation pressure, it is just the ambient pressure in the star.  The equations here are the same as hydrostatic equilibrium in the earth's atmosphere.  The outward pressure has to equal the sum of the inward pressure and the gravitational force on the cylinder.  That gives a relationship between the fall of pressure and the mass density of the gas.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Would you mind addressing the other questions I have also? Particularly the issues with the negative signs.

Comment: Is the inward pressure $P(r +\delta r) \gt P(r)$? With $P(r+\delta r)$ being the inward pressure and $P(r)$ being the outward pressure, as in the diagram.

Comment: No, the pressure is decreasing with altitude, so $P(r+\delta r) \lt P(r)$  The pressure is the same in all directions at any given altitude.

Answer (score -1):

In the star, light does not travel far before being scattered.  Its pressure acts in all directions, not just outward.